# Plain insert vs plsql insert - pros and cons

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What I need to do is inserting records into table TAB_B which come as a result from select to table TAB_A (tables are identical in structure), like that:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TAB_B SELECT * FROM TAB_A WHERE [CONDITION]
```

The thing is that i need to know how many records were inserted, so the easiest way is to count them after inserting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB_A WHERE [CONDITION]
```

Anyway, it would be great if I could omit executing query with the same condition twice, so I could do:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TAB_B SELECT * FROM TAB_A WHERE [CONDITION];
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

The question is:
"Does plsql solution have any cons - especially in terms of PERFORMANCE? Should I stick to INSERT followed by COUNT, or not?"

EDIT
Gentleman, I think my question can't be asked more clearly and it is about PERFORMANCE DIFFERENCES plus eventual drawbacks, not the method itself (I tried to state it better in title and question itself). The question you marked as a duplicate is about how to count rows whether my question is which of those two methods is better in terms of performance and if there are any drawbacks while using any of mentioned methods.

Comment: there is no disadvantage in running the insert in a pl/sql block vs outside a block.

Comment: Not sure about the context, but if you are calling this from code, you would usually be doing something like `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`, which usually has an int as return type telling you the amount of rows affected. Not sure if that would help, as you didn't mention any context other than the database itself.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're doing this in PL/SQL (as indicated by the tag), the easiest way to accomplish what you want would be to use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`, as in:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO TAB_B SELECT * FROM TAB_A WHERE [CONDITION];

nRows_inserted := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```

To know how many rows were actually inserted using COUNT(*) query you'd have to execute it once before making the inserts and again after to account for the possibility that there might be rows in the table which already satisfy the condition before you perform the insert.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Please read again my question, it's about the difference in performance in presented methods. Also, I can count the number of inserted rows querying source table.

Comment: Why the downvote? this is exactly what is answerd - if you're inside plsql the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` is better since it doesn't run a query twice

Comment: It says you cannot find the number of inserted rows with only one `select`, since there may be rows satisfying the condition before your insert. Even if you execute another `select` before the `insert`, there may be insertions or deletions to the table. So yes, you should stick to `SQL%ROWCOUNT`